# Correlating vector data with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vector, cross-correlation

I have a time series of vector data -- each point being a 2D vector.  I would like to calculate an autocorrelation (or something like it -- excuse me if I'm misusing the language here).  Let's say the vector at time t is v(t).  What I want is to calculate vector dot products so that my correlation looks like:

C(T) = ∑ v⃗(t) · v⃗(t+T)

summed over all t s.t. v(t) and v(t+T) exist.

Is there a clean, compact way to do this with numpy?  (Would be happy to give a try to answers from scipy etc. too.)  Thanks.

Comment: Over which variable is the sum? I assume over `t` for all values such that `v(t)` and `v(t+T)` exist?

Comment: @Nabla Thanks for the improvement.  Can you point me to a source for putting math characters into the text on this site.  I tied the standard LaTeX stuff -- like they use over at the StackEx math site, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Nabla  Yes, that's right.  I edited the question and added that bit of info.

Comment: There is sadly no LaTeX here, I used unicode symbols: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode. See the source of my edit for how to enter them in html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume `v` has the following format:

```
v = numpy.array( [[1,2], [4,2], [15,34], [2,3]] )
```

Extract the two components:

```
v1 = v[:,0]
v2 = v[:,1]
```

Then use correlate to calculate the per-component correlation:

```
C = numpy.correlate(v1,v1,'full') + numpy.correlate(v2,v2,'full')
```

You will only need half of the result as the correlation is symmetric. The correct half would be:

```
C = C[(len(C)/2):]
```

Comment: Thanks.  Pretty clear now that I see it.  Much obliged.