# Vectorize correlation function with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have written a small function that computes the correlation of two signals at a given time *t* and a given lag *dt*. This function is then called for many values of *t* and many values of *dt*. For example, `t = linspace(0, 10000, 1000)` and `dt=range(-20, 20)`.

From what I can see in numpy, I may be able to vectorize along *dt* by using `np.correlate` with the right subarrays **when *dt* is a range with step 1 and not a linspace**

I am looking for solutions for vectorizing along *t* and possibly along *dt* when *dt* is not a range with step 1. I am looking for a solution with memory complexity O(t*dt + s1 + s2).

Anyway to do this correctly with numpy directly? Perhaps numba should be the solution (perhaps it's time to learn numba...)?

```py
def correlate(s1, s2, t, bef, after, dt):
    t, bef, after, dt = int(t), int(bef), int(after), int(dt)

    if t-bef < 0 or t-bef + dt<0 or t+after >= s1.size or t+dt+after >= s2.size:
        return np.nan
    return (s1[t-bef: t+after] * s2[t+dt-bef: t+dt+after]).sum()
```

Thanks for any advice you can provide...

**Note**: I do not believe this [np.einsum trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43768426/numpy-vectorization-functions) works and simply calling np.correlate as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819989/correlating-vector-data-with-numpy) is not what I am searching for.

**Bonus**: If the code could be vectorized over s1 and s2 as in the use case given below, that would be a nice bonus.

**Small xarray code to test**

```py
import numpy as np, xarray as xr, numexpr as ne, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = xr.Dataset()
dataset = dataset.assign_coords(t=np.linspace(0,100*np.pi, 2000))
dataset["fs"] = xr.apply_ufunc(lambda t: 1/(t[1]-t[0]), dataset["t"], input_core_dims=[["t"]])
dataset = dataset.assign_coords(s1=["where(t< 150,cos(t),cos(2*t))", "cos(t+pi/2)"], s2= ["cos(t)", "cos(t+pi/2)", "cos(t+pi/3)"])
dataset["signal_1"] = xr.apply_ufunc(lambda expr, t: ne.evaluate(expr, dict(t=t, pi=np.pi))
    , dataset["s1"], dataset["t"], input_core_dims=[[], ["t"]], output_core_dims=["t"], vectorize=True)
dataset["signal_2"] = xr.apply_ufunc(lambda expr, t: ne.evaluate(expr, dict(t=t, pi=np.pi))
    , dataset["s2"], dataset["t"], input_core_dims=[[], ["t"]], output_core_dims=["t"], vectorize=True)

#It really starts here

dataset = dataset.assign_coords(dt=np.linspace(-10*np.pi, 10*np.pi, 500))
dataset["dt_fs"] = xr.apply_ufunc(lambda t: 1/(t[1]-t[0]), dataset["dt"], input_core_dims=[["dt"]])
dataset = dataset.assign_coords(t_corr=np.linspace(0*np.pi, 100*np.pi, 100))

def correlate(s1, s2, t, bef, after, dt):
    t, bef, after, dt = int(t), int(bef), int(after), int(dt)

    if t-bef < 0 or t-bef + dt<0 or t+after >= s1.size or t+dt+after >= s2.size:
        return np.nan
    return (s1[t-bef: t+after] * s2[t+dt-bef: t+dt+after]).sum()

dataset["correlate"]= xr.apply_ufunc(correlate, dataset["signal_1"], dataset["signal_2"], 
    dataset["t_corr"]*dataset["fs"], 5*np.pi*dataset["fs"], 5*np.pi*dataset["fs"], dataset["dt"]*dataset["fs"],
    input_core_dims=[["t"]]*2+[[]]*4, vectorize=True
)
```

Comment: Every time is good to learn `numba`. I have trouble understanding why you can't use `np.correlate`. You are not working on some floating point indices and interpolation of the signals, right?